# Sequentially number rows by keyed group in SQL?

Tags: sql, row-number, sequential

Is there a way in SQL to sequentially add a row number **by key group**?

Assume a table with arbitrary (CODE,NAME) tuples.  Example table:

```
CODE NAME    
---- ----
A    Apple
A    Angel
A    Arizona
B    Bravo
C    Charlie
C    Cat
D    Dog
D    Doppler
D    Data
D    Down
```

Desired projection using CODE as the grouping attribute:

```
CODE C_NO NAME    
---- ---- ----
A    0    Apple
A    1    Angel
A    2    Arizona
B    0    Bravo
C    1    Charlie
C    0    Cat
D    0    Dog
D    1    Data
D    2    Down
D    3    Doppler
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)
- [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)
- [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html)
- [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb262.htm)
- [MySQL 8.0+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)
- [MariaDB 10.2+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/)
- [SQLite 3.25+](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html)

This covers most bases.

```
SELECT
    CODE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY NAME) - 1 As C_NO,
    NAME
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: Was wondering if this could be agnostic, but it is on Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL (and probably most other databases):

```
select g.CODE
     , count(*)-1 as C_NO
     , g.NAME
from MyTable as g
  left join MyTable as o
    on g.CODE = o.CODE
      and g.NAME >= o.NAME
group by g.CODE
       , g.NAME;
```

---

Specific to MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE NumberRowsByGroup()
BEGIN
  SET  @code := 0;
  SET  @num := 0;
  SELECT CODE, C_NO, NAME FROM
    ( select q.CODE
           , q.NAME
           , @num := IF(q.CODE = @code, @num + 1, 0) as C_NO
           , @code := q.CODE as previous
      from yourTable q
      order by CODE
             , NAME
    ) as p
  ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, we can call:

```
CALL NumberRowsByGroup();
```

According to xaprb.com/blog post: [how-to-number-rows-in-mysql](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/), the second is faster.

Comment: The first solution isn't needed on other RDBMS that have windowing functions